# Creating a Queue in C++ - What is a malloc error?

Tags: c++, queue, nodes

I am creating a simple queue, however I am getting a weird error:

compile(46096,0x7fffb263d380) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9c61c00340: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

If I reduce the number of enqueue methods I just get a segmentation fault.

My main class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"
using namespace std;

template <typename ItemType>
void enqueue(const ItemType &i, node<ItemType>* &n, const long &p) {

    node<ItemType> *nn = new node<ItemType>;

    nn->item = i;
    nn->next = n;
    n = nn;
}

template <typename ItemType>
ItemType dequeue(node<ItemType>* &n) {

    ItemType fr;
    node<ItemType> *ptr;

    ptr=n;
    n = n->next;
    while(ptr->next != NULL){
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    fr = ptr->item;

    delete ptr;
    return fr;

}


int main() {

    node<int> *head;
    enqueue(13,head, 1);
    enqueue(10,head, 2);
    enqueue(18,head, 3);
    cout<<head->item<<"\t"<<head->next->item<<"\t"<<head->next->next->item<<endl;
    cout<<dequeue(head)<<"\t";
    cout<<dequeue(head)<<"\t";
    cout<<dequeue(head)<<endl;

    //cout<<dequeue(head)<<endl; // create error cathcing

}
```

My node wrapper class:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ItemType>
struct node {
    ItemType item;
    node<ItemType> *next;
    int priority;
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `std::queue` instead of rolling your own manually? In any case, you are not initializing `head` to null before using it, so you have nodes with invalid `next` values

Comment: Seems like the runtime is telling you the exact problem. I mean ***error for object 0x7f9c61c00340: pointer being freed was not allocated*** why I mention this is you don't always get such a detailed error message.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 3):

You do: `node<int> *head;` and then enqueue it with `nn->next = n;`

This ends up storing unintialized memory, then fails at deletion.

Try `node<int> *head = NULL;`

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `NULL` instead of `nullptr`?

Comment: Probably because the code in the question uses `NULL` instead.

Comment: it prints the same number (13) for every dequeue. however it did remove the error